# Xamarin pcl store user data how?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios

Ok so using xamarin mvvmcross. Trying to create a cross app android ios app which uses a pcl project.

I'm trying to save user data locally in the pcl project. Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried using the AccountStore.Create() but got the following:

Portable Bait And Switch is nuget feature, so the package must be installed in all project. NotImplementedException will indicate that Portable Code from PCL is used and not Platform Specific implementation. Please check whether platform specific Assembly is properly installed. Cannot save account in Portable profile - bite-and-switch error.Please file a bug in https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Would i have to use sqllite dbs to store data locally instead of accoutstore stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this plugin
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Settings/
this stores data without using sqlite using platform specific methods like shared preferences in android.

Comment: In the pcl project when i try to store the values I get the following:

This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.

I have enabled the nuget package on the android UI side as well but i still get that. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Neil you have to add that nuget package in Android and iOS Project as well in order to make it work.

Comment: Was always getting "This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly." error had to clean the project and compile seemed to do the trick. Thanks again for the help Zain!

Answer (score 0):

For security reason, I wouldn't recommend storing it in SharedPreferences or local Sqlite DB.

In the core project, you should have a security services, something like this:

```
namespace CustomerMobile.Core.Services.Interfaces
{
    public interface ISecureStorageService
    {
        void Store(string key, string value);
        void Delete(string key);
        string GetValue(string key);
    }
}
```

Then, for Android project, I recommend Plugin.SecureStorage nuget package. The implementation should be something like this below:

```
namespace CustomerMobile.Droid.Services
{
    public class SecureStorageService : ISecureStorageService
    {
        public SecureStorageService()
        {
            SecureStorageImplementation.StoragePassword = "security_password";
        }

        public void Delete(string key)
        {
            CrossSecureStorage.Current.DeleteKey(key);
        }

        public string GetValue(string key)
        {
            return CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue(key);
        }

        public void Store(string key, string value)
        {
            CrossSecureStorage.Current.SetValue(key, value);
        }

    }
}
```

Finally, this one is for iOS, where I recommend Square.Valet nuget package:

```
namespace CustomerMobile.iOS.Services
{
    public class SecureStorageService : ISecureStorageService
    {
        private const string _userKey = "GlobalApp";

        public void Delete(string key)
        {
            var valet = new Valet(_userKey, Accessibility.WhenUnlocked);

            valet.RemoveObject(key);
        }

        public void Store(string key, string value)
        {
            var valet = new Valet(_userKey, Accessibility.WhenUnlocked);

            valet.SetString(value, key);
        }

        public string GetValue(string key)
        {
            string value = string.Empty;

            var valet = new Valet(_userKey, Accessibility.WhenUnlocked);

            value = valet.GetString(key);

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

References:
Valet Nuget package: [Square.Valet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square.Valet/2.2.0)

Android SecureStorage: [SecureStorage](https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage)

Comment: thanks for that but i'm a bit confused here on the implementation. Can I store the information int he pcl project? Or would I need to specifically store it in the android or IOS project. i'm using mvvmcross so doing all the grunt work in the core pcl project. can this not be done?

Comment: yeah it is the mvvm cross implementation. You identify the Interface in the core project. Then you just need to call the interface in the native project.

Comment: But wouldn't that create a circular reference? Currently:
UI (android) ->  Core project

New:
UI (android) <->  Core project. 

Wouldnt you want to save the items in the core project instead? Otherwise the mvvm structure seems pointless?

Comment: It is actually the right approach for mvvm cross. I will give you an example why I always implement the interface in the Core project, then extend that Interface in my native project. The scenario is that if you want to open an external browser link with custom settings:
1. In your Core project: public interface IExternalBrowserService
 {
  void OpenUrl(string url);
 }
2. In your Android project:

Comment: public class ExternalBrowseService :IExternalBrowserService
 {
  public ExternalBrowseService()
  {
  }

  public void OpenUrl(string url)
  {
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) 
   { 
    return;
   }

   if (!url.StartsWith("http://") && !url.StartsWith("https://")) 
   {
    url = "http://" + url;
   }
    

   var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url));
   intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

   Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
  }
 }

Comment: 3. In your iOS project: 
public class ExternalBrowserService: IExternalBrowserService
 {
  public void OpenUrl(string url)
  {
   UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(url));
  }
 }

Comment: Basically, only the business logic and the structure is shared. The rest will inherit from the Core project.